# n-bit ALU usually do comparison operation on maximum n/2-bit or n-bit?

Tags: comparison, equality

For n-bit ALU is equal-to operation and similar comparisons generally limited to n/2-bit words, or n-bit?

Comment: Presumably, $n$-bit ALUs work on arguments which $n$-bit long. The output could be even longer, though this is not the case here.

Comment: OK thanks. So a 1-bit computer actually uses 2 bit when it does addition etc? That explains why 1-bit computer seems to be a thing, I assumed a 2-bit computer would be minimum viable computer.

Comment: When adding two $n$-bit numbers, the result is an $n$-bit number, and perhaps and updating of the carry bit.

Comment: Yes I know that. But the input is 2 n-bit numbers. The bus has to move 2 n-bit, not just one. I'm a noob, I just assumed a 1-bit computer was impossible but if they can work with 2x1-bit it makes sense.

Comment: Big thanks anyhow! As a person very new to computer science, and in the beginning of learning about it, it is very helpful to sort out some of the basic concepts. Now I understand why 1-bit computers actually seem to be a thing... Peace!

Comment: I think the very first microprocessor was a 4 bit computer (Intel 4004). You wouldn't build a 1 bit computer because you would need so much more code and time doing anything useful.

Comment: I'm not an expert. I equated 1-bit to only being able to have one input. But if the definition is more that inputs are 1-bit, then I guess it would be able to do stuff with it. I saw content online about 1-bit cpus while I was wondering about that a few weeks ago, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-bit_computing. But don't know much about that. Peace!